# How to download and use jface

Tags: java, swt, jface

I want to use JFace with my own java program, but I am not sure about how to get it.

There does not seem to be any independent download project like there is for Swt.

I did some googling and found some old threads which said I just had to take the jar files from eclipse. Is this really the best way to get JFace?

I tried to add the following jar files from my eclipse/plugins folder:

org.eclipse.jface_3.13.2.v20171022-1656.jar
org.eclipse.jface.databinding_1.8.100.v20170503-1507.jar
org.eclipse.jface.text_3.12.1.v20171114-1359.jar

When I add them to my project I can compile a simple JFace test program, but when I try to run it I get

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/runtime/ISafeRunnable

So which dependencies does JFace have on eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...] I just had to take the jar files from eclipse. Is this really the best way to get JFace?

As far as I know, yes.

> So which dependencies does JFace have on eclipse?

To use JFace you should include these jars from the eclipse/plugins folder:

```
org.eclipse.core.commands_<version info>.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.common_<version info>.jar
org.eclipse.jface_<version info>.jar
org.eclipse.osgi_<version info>.jar
org.eclipse.ui.workbench_<version info>.jar  -> not required but recommended
```

For more information see https://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace.

Comment: Thank, that seems to solve it. What about org.eclipse.jface.databinding_1.8.100.v20170503-1507.jar ./plugins/org.eclipse.jface.text_3.12.1.v20171114-1359.jar ? They sound like they are part of JFace from the name, but are not mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: @MTilsted Not sure, I never needed them myself.

Comment: @LorisSecuro I dont have those files in my plugin folder. I only have 1 file called `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356` Would you know why?